# Can you run two PHYSICAL devices in Xcode 12.0.0+ BOTH using the same codebase/files?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, simulator

This question has been asked multiple times with no clear answer with anything over Xcode 9.0.0, so I'm wondering in **Xcode 12.0.0+** if you can run the same app/code through xcode to launch on one physical device, and then launch another xcode instance on a DIFFERENT physical phone?

I've tried with multiple simulators with no success (just closes the old one and starts a new instance on the 2nd device closing the first).

Comment: You can launch multiple instances of your app from Xcode on both physical devices and simulators. Simply launch the first instance and then select the other target device and click run a second time.  I have done this frequently when working on Bluetooth apps and I need to debug both sides simultaneously. You can just select the required running target at the bottom of the window to see the debugger and console output you require

Comment: To clarify, you can run on multiple physical devices simultaneously but only one simulator instance can be running under Xcode; So you could run a copy on your phone, a copy on your iPad and a copy on a simulator, for example.

Comment: Paul.... dude thank you... for-real. I am building a social media version of upwork and coding/wiring up the video interviews for applicants with Twilo's REST api which is what led me to ask this question. Thank you for the confirmation and information. I appreciate you going into detail for me, I understand now. Hope the bluetooth apps went well! Nice people like yourself deserve good things.

Comment: You might consider [unified logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/), where you can log events on a device and watch them from your macOS console. So run one device through the Xcode debugger, and watch your `Logger` or `OSLog` statements on the other device through the macOS console. It’s a good way to monitor processes between two devices. (Unified logging is also great for monitoring processes that would otherwise be affected by being connected to a debugger, such as app lifecycle events.)

Comment: Mhmmmm... Thanks Rob! I'll check this out, I didn't know about unified logging. Thanks for the tip. Ideally I would like to debug both processes so this is def worth looking into.